# array_unique showing error Array to string conversion

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

For getting the unique values i am using unique values. Below is the code i am using

```
array_unique($results_external);
aasort($results_external,"created_on");
$returns_buy_external[]=array_reverse($results_external, true);
```

If i use the code like this, below is the error i am getting

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: models/product_model.php
>
> Line Number: 3550

3550 line is array_unique($results_external);

Can anyone help me, why it is getting error like this and how to solve it?

results_external sample format coming is below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 144
            [name] => test
            [slug] => test
            [images] => {"9eebd0f69772dd3bdf8c787864437c85":{"filename":"9eebd0f69772dd3bdf8c787864437c85.png","alt":"TRESemme Smooth and Shine","caption":""}}
            [track_stock] => 1
            [seo_title] => ttt
            [qty] => 0
            [product_type] => 0
            [price] => 0.00
            [saleprice] => 0.00
            [external_links] => http://test.com
            [external_price] => 285.00
            [external_saleprice] => 285.00
            [created_on] => 2013-11-08 15:03:24
        )
)
```

Comment: 3550 line is array_unique($results_external);

Comment: What's the content of $results_external?

Comment: Please `Print_r($results_external)` and post

Comment: i printed pls check it out

Comment: aasort? was it supposed to be asort()?.

Comment: use `array_unique($results_external[0])`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

Comment: @Naruto isssue is solved by addding array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));

Answer (score 121, accepted):

As per [the docs](http://php.net/array-unique), `array_unique` compares elements as strings by default. This means your 2D array is being converted to an array of strings (all being `"Array"` and generating the array-to-string Notice) or which only one can be returned as unique.

Use the `SORT_REGULAR` flag to compare the elements as they are, but be aware that arrays are only considered equal if they have the same key-value pairs.

**Example:**

```
print_r(array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR));
```

Comment: after upgrading ( finally ) to php7 there are lots of errors to clear up and this little nugget resolved some of them!